# I would like to know how to add location to dynamic textboxes in asp.net C# !

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to specify location for dynamically occurring textbox however i am unable to do so as the "Location" property doesn't work saying I am missing some namespace.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;




protected void freq_txtbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(e_freq.Text);
        int c = 0;
        for (c = 0; c <= num; c++)
        {
            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Location= new Point(100,20*c);
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);

        }      
    }
```

Comment: `Webforms` texbox does not contain property Location.

Comment: Why you want to set location for textboxes simply create a div for each textbox and set styling of div to adjust the texboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `Location` in `WebForms TextBox`.

So what you can do is create a `container div` for every textbox and set styling for each `div` to adjust the position of divs.

```
for (c = 0; c <= num; c++)
{
  TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
  HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
  div.Controls.Add(txtRun);
  div.Attributes.Add("class", "txtContainer");
  divContainer.Controls.Add(div);

}
```

And here is styling for container div surrounding textboxes

```
<style>
   .txtContainer {
       width: 15%;
       float:left;
       padding:10px;
   }
</style>
```

And here is main container div

```
<div runat="server" id="divContainer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding dynamically created TextBox control to *webform* using this you can make a container like asp.net `Panel` or `div` a server accessible control by assigning it `id` and setting `runat` property to *"server"*.

```
divId.Controls.Add(txtRun);
```

The declaration of div in html would be like

```
<div id="divId" runat="server"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is WinForm style for add any text box.
You can create a jQuery code for add text boxes

enter code here

```
function AddNewTextBoxes(noOfTextBoxNeeded){
   var varHtmlTextbox="";
   for(var i=0;i<noOfTextBoxNeeded;i++){
       varHtmlTextbox = varHtmlTextbox + "<input type='text' /> <br/>";  
   }

   $("#DivToAppenTextboxes").append(varHtmlTextbox);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Take a div where you can add your controls in it. 
suppose

Client side

```
<style>
.btnClass{
//your css is going to implement here whatever you want.
}
</style>

<div id="dvId" runat="server"></div>
```

What will be the server side code, here we need to apply css to button which is going to add in our Div controller:

```
 for (c = 0; c <= num; c++)
        {
            TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Attributes.Add("class", "btnClass");
            dvId.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        }
```